# Get all combinations of some column's values and column names into one row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of data frames, all of which are the same dimensions (64 obs, 12 variables). I need to "flatten" these data frames in such a way that I return with 64 x 11 = 704 variables and one observation, deriving all combinations of one column that has all unique values and the column names of the data frame. Examples are provided below.

I have attempted using `acast` and `melt` to achieve this. However, the supporting operations both pre and post melt make this approach slow when having to lapply this approach over 100k+ data frames.

Here is an example data frame and my taken approach:

```
df <- data.frame(var1=c(1,2,3),name=c("these","are","names"),var3=c(4,NA,NA),var4=c(NA,NA,5),var6=c(NA,5,NA))

flattening <- function(df){
  rownames(df) <- df$name
  df$name <- NULL
  df <- melt(as.matrix(df)) %>% group_by(name = paste0(Var1,"_",Var2)) %>% summarise(
    value = first(value)
  ) %>% data.frame()

  cnames <- df$name
  df <- data.frame(values=df$value) %>% t() %>% data.frame()
  names(df) <- cnames
  df
}

flattening(df)
```

The example df looks as such:

```
  var1  name var3 var4 var6
1    1 these    4   NA   NA
2    2   are   NA   NA    5
3    3 names   NA    5   NA
```

I am looking for the expected outcome:

```
       are_var1 are_var3 are_var4 are_var6 names_var1 names_var3 names_var4 names_var6 these_var1 these_var3 these_var4 these_var6
values        2       NA       NA        5          3         NA          5         NA          1          4         NA         NA
```

RESULTS UPDATE:

I have a microbenchmark below where `expr` is the user's handle:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval cld
    old 78.370093 81.038799 90.272721 85.694885 89.304528 1114.03968   500   c
 tmfmnk 11.829791 12.697675 13.844833 13.134485 13.623065   34.91430   500  b 
    s_t  1.476159  1.774409  2.030418  1.873876  2.003681   16.89159   500 a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `reshape2::melt()` then use base R:

```
library(reshape2)
dats <- melt(df) 
rownames(dats) <- paste0(dats$name,'-',dats$variable)
dats <- t(dats)
dats <- dats[-c(1,2),]
dats <- sapply(dats,as.numeric)
dats

these-var1   are-var1 names-var1 these-var3   are-var3 names-var3 these-var4   are-var4 names-var4 these-var6   are-var6 
         1          2          3          4         NA         NA         NA         NA          5         NA          5 
names-var6 
        NA
```

**edit**

Here as `data.frame`:

```
dats <- as.data.frame.matrix(t(as.data.frame.numeric(dats)))
```

Comment: So far your solution is by far the most efficient. Let's see if anyone can trump it. However, I had to add the following to the `sapply` stage to fit my use case (I'm using lapply across a list of dataframes with your solution). Any chance you can thing of a faster alternative?

```dats <- data.frame(t(sapply(dats,as.numeric)))```

Comment: @JonathanRauscher not sure of understanding, but you can use this to convert it as data.frame :  `dats <- as.data.frame.matrix(t(as.data.frame.numeric(dats)))` that has class data.frame.

Comment: That works a-lot better. Mind updating your answer with that?

Answer (score 2):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 gather(var, val, -2) %>%
 mutate(var = paste(name, var, sep = "_")) %>%
 select(-name) %>%
 spread(var, val)

  are_var1 are_var3 are_var4 are_var6 names_var1 names_var3 names_var4 names_var6
1        2       NA       NA        5          3         NA          5         NA
  these_var1 these_var3 these_var4 these_var6
1          1          4         NA         NA
```

It should be faster than you original approach, however, there are certainly faster possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dcast` from `data.table` which can take multiple `value.var` columns

```
library(data.table)
out <- dcast(setDT(df)[, rn := 1], rn ~ name, 
          value.var = paste0("var", c(1, 3, 4, 6)))[, rn := NULL][]
setnames(out, sub("([^_]+)_([^_]+)", "\\2_\\1", names(out)))
out
#   are_var1 names_var1 these_var1 are_var3 names_var3 these_var3 are_var4 names_var4 these_var4 are_var6 names_var6 these_var6
#1:        2          3          1       NA         NA          4       NA          5         NA        5         NA         NA
```